# how to know if a Google Form has been submitted by the user in a web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to use Google Forms in my webapp to run quizzes.

1. The Google Form is created.
2. I use the pre-fill option to get a URL.
3. From my web app I create an iframe and pass the URL (different for each user) by passing the user-id to the form.
4. User now fills the form and submits.
5. The data is stored in a spreadsheet.
6. Earlier I publish the spreadsheet (thereby making it public).
7. I can now access the spreadsheet data and update my local database.

So currently, when the user submits (from within Google Form) there is no way my web app knows about it. (I have browsed the internet for solutions but did not find any).

Is there a way to get around this?

Currently, at some "stage" in the web app, I check if the user form data is available in the database. If not, I check the spreadsheet for that user data. If found, update the webapp database. So in that sense the webapp uses a pull-feature to check for updates.

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, if the values are put to the Spreadsheet when Google Form is submitted, how about using the form's submit trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727771/close-htmlservice-popup

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike I need to trigger something on the browser side where the form is being shown ... so that my webapp can do whatever logic is required to change status etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to know when a new Form response has been uploaded. If my understanding of the question is correct, then you could use a simple [`.onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger in the response Sheet. As an alternative, you could use a [`FormResponse.submit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#submit) installable trigger that fires at each response. Please keep in mind that triggers are limited to form uploads that don't fire from API requests and script executions, as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions). Please, don't hesitate to ask for further clarification.

---

## UPDATE

Based on your last comment I get that your priority is to see the response Sheet updated in real time. If my understanding of the issue is correct, then you can show the responses Sheet directly in a webapp inside an iframe. Please, ask me any question if you have doubts about this approach.

Comment: Thanks @Jacques-Guzel Heron. I have used the FormResponse Submit but it fires at best a backend api call. While I am wondering if there is a way in which some function in the browser window inside which (iframe) the google form resides can be called?

Comment: Hi there @RmR! I just updated my answer based on the new information. Please, take a look and let me know any if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-Guzel Heron. To clarify again, when the user submits the Google form, it updates the spreadsheet. The Google form (in my case) is in an iframe of the main browser window. My need is: can some function in the main browser window be called when the user clicks on the submit button of the Google Form. From what I could understand from your response is: that we can have another iframe in  the main browser window that accesses the google sheet directly, right? In which case we may have to use the auth route .. and also may need to poll the sheet continuously checking for updates

Comment: @RmR I now understand that your priority is to run a function in your webpage (inside an iframe) when the user submits the Form. Did I get it right? Also please clarify if your function is an [Apps Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) or not.

Comment: Yes @Jacques. That is correct. The function is a normal javascript function running in the local browser of the user

Comment: @RmR Please take a look at [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) to duplicate your current Javascript function. Then, you will be able to create [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that fire when the Form is uploaded.

Comment: Thanks @Jacques. Will take a look. Sorry for the late response. Was unusually busy on some work.