# Show a popup/dialog when clicking submit on an embedded google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google sites page where I embedded a google form.
When users click submit, the page doesn't scroll up and they don't see the (Google form confirmation page) unless they scroll up.
Is there a way to make a popup message appear when the user clicks submit?

I tried to create a script to show a dialog, but it only appears on the editor side, and on load:

**Code.gs**

```
function onSubmit() {
  FormApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  FormApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Your response has been submitted');
}
```

**Page.html**

`Thank you! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />`

Is there a workaround? thanks

Comment: @TheMaster .. there is a workaround if you can use google app scripts and use javascript to store the details in a google spreadsheet instead of google form

Comment: @HymnZzy I don't bypassing google form can be considered a workaround.

Comment: @TheMaster .. it's an alternate solution where you skip Google form completely and store the data in the spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

If the form is embedded in a iframe, clicking submit button on the form does fire a `load` event on the iframe.  Depending on the number of sections in the form, You may be able to use it to detect  the final submit event. Note that this works  best if there are no sections on your Google form and it's a single page form.

See [Related Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727771)